# Having Trouble Inserting Array Possibly Due to Table Structure

Tags: mysql, arrays, data-structures, insert, auto-increment

Here is a screenshot of the table structure:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0By2lFlhEzILjYlM4SjdhdFNpbk0/edit?usp=sharing

When I am attempting the following `INSERT INTO` sql command of an array, I get a blank page (running locally).  Here is the sql action:

```
foreach($insertProductMap as $rowEntry => $virtuemartProductPrice)

   {


$sql_updateProductPrice = "INSERT INTO `$abc_virtuemart_product_prices` (`virtuemart_product_price_id`, `virtuemart_product_id`, `virtuemart_shoppergroup_id`, `product_price`, `override`, `product_override_price`, `product_tax_id`, `product_discount_id`, `product_currency`, `product_price_publish_up`, `product_price_publish_down`, `price_quantity_start`, `price_quantity_end`, `created_on`, `created_by`, `modified_on`, `modified_by`, `locked_on`, `locked_by`) VALUES ('5', '0', NULL, '".mysql_real_escape_string($virtuemartProductPrice)."', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0')";

mysql_query($sql_updateProductPrice);

   }
```

This is just one of the many iterations that I have attempted to update this table.  I have tested a similar array insert on other tables and it works fine.  This is what is leading me to believe that there must be something with the database structure which I am improperly calling.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL errors don't break pages as far as I know.

Is there any other code on the page? If there is no other code on your page, the problem would be that nothing is being told to display on the page. If it's PHP, try putting `ini_set("display_errors","1");` at the start of your script to display errors.

If you still don't see any errors, try putting `echo "a";` at the top of your script and reload your page. You should see an "a". Continue to move this line down your script; if you see it, this line is before your error, if you don't see it, this line is after your error.

Also, you need to sanitize your inputs not only to prevent [SQL injection](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php), but to keep apostrophes from breaking things.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I have this being run through a php script.  The script will load 100% using the echo call as you noted.  I am now displaying errors at the top of the script and have a few "undefined variables."  I am going to look into these and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I have defined the variables, but now the problem is that the script does not insert an array of values.  It will only insert 1 line from the array.

Comment: An array isn't a string, so you can't just save it to a database like you can a normal variable. However, you can convert an array into a string if you use the [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) functions.